# jslint stops at $(document).ready line

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

I am encountering a problem with JSLint and it is providing an incomprehensible error:

I am attempting to analyze code of the following structure:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var MyGlobalObj = MyGlobalObj || {}; //used for creating namespace security

    MyGlobalObj.MyFunction = function () {
        //valid javascript
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Stuff I want analyzed
    });
</script>
```

I am using a mix of javascript and jQuery in my code. However, JSLint claims that, on the line with the ready operation, that:

```
Unexpected '$'.
        $(document).ready(function() {
```

I'm sorry but... what? Why is that unexpected? What is the "correct" implementation?

```
Options I am using:
    /*jslint white: true, browser: true, devel: true */
Entry in the predef box:
    $
```

Note: Elsewhere, I have no problems declaring $(variable) as needed. It's just that one line.

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript, you cannot use a mixture of it ;) What's the line before `$(document).ready(...)`? If there is an "unexpected something", then the symbol is not expected because of the stuff that came before.

Comment: @FelixKling You use a mixture of English and Poetry when you speak~

Comment: @TheZ Poetry itself is not a language, just like jQuery is not a language.

Comment: @Ibu It was a joke, and Poetry cannot live without language. Language is it's medium as well as its substance. Language is communication, and poetry is applied communication. Has Jabberwocky taught you nothing? xD

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to validate my jQuery JavaScript with JSLint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071467/is-it-possible-to-validate-my-jquery-javascript-with-jslint)

Comment: This is most likely an error in the code just before that line. Try commenting out that line and re-running jslint.

Comment: I've read on the site for jslint, or maybe somewhere else I don't remember. But jslint is one mans definition of what javascript should look like. Its also based on native javascript syntax and not supportive of jquery's syntax. I remember running into a similar problem. When validating jquery or any library really thats its a hit or miss, sometimes it validates sometimes it doesn't

Comment: Just to make sure: if you remove the `$(document).ready()` part completely, everything else validates?

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you. I looked back at the code with your comments in mind, and found that JSLint was expecting a semicolon on the curly brace before the $ sign. I have updated the question and provided an answer to explain better why this error was encountered. JSLint is now happy with my code :)

Answer (score 0):

An unexpected collision of JSLint priorities occurred to produce this error.

Per the JSLint documentation on semicolons:

> JSLint expects that every statement be followed by `;` except for
>       `for`, `function`, `if`, `switch`, `try`, and `while`. JSLint does not expect
>       to see unnecessary semicolons or the empty statement.

To provide namespace protection, I implemented namespaces according to tutorials found here:

http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/26/basic-javascript-part-8-namespaces/

However, when assigning a new variable to a named object, JSLint (and apparently standard convention) holds that the code

```
Obj.Method = function (TheArgs) { /*do stuff*/ };
```

should be followed by a semicolon, regardless of the use of the function keyword. This derives from the assignment operator's requirement for a semi-colon superseding the function keyword's omission of a semi-colon.

Thanks go to Felix Kling for pointing out that "unexpected" indicates that the code immediately prior to the unexpected line did not conclude correctly.

Comment: Assignment statements should always be terminated with a semicolon :) In this case, `function() {...}` is not a statement but an *expression* (since it is on the right-hand side of the assignment), so the exceptions you quoted do not apply here.

Answer (score 0):

This is the JSLint valied version of that code.

1. Add semicolons
2. Use strict

   /*global $, document */

   "use strict";

   var MyGlobalObj = MyGlobalObj || {}; //used for creating namespace security

   MyGlobalObj.MyFunction = function () {
   //  valid javascript
   };

   $(document).ready(function () {
   //  Stuff I want analyzed
   });