# What's wrong with this jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Could anyone please explain why this function doesn't work?

```
<form id="spot-search">
    <label for="text-basic">Postcode</label>
    <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" value="">
    </br>
    <label for="slider">within mile radius</label>
    <input type="range" name="radius" id="radius" value="50" min="0" max="200">
    </br>
    <label>Select spot type</label>
    <a href="#spot-type" data-role="button">All</a>
    </br>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

<div id="map1">
    map 1 goes here
</div>
<div id="map2">
    map 2 goes here
</div>
<div id="map3">
    map 3 goes here
</div>
<div id="map4">
    map 4 goes here
</div>
<div id="map5">
    map 5 goes here
</div>
```

When submitted should run this function:

```
$('#spot-search').submit(function(e) {
    var radius = getElementById('#radius');

    if ($radius<=40) {
        $('#spot-search').hide();
        $('#map1').show();
    } elseif($radius>40 && $radius<=80) {
        $('#spot-search').hide();
        $('#map2').show();
    } elseif($radius>80 && $radius<=120) {
        $('#spot-search').hide();
        $('#map3').show();
    } elseif($radius>120 && $radius<=160) {
        $('#spot-search').hide();
        $('#map4').show();
    } elseif($radius>160 && $radius<=200) {
        $('#spot-search').hide();
        $('#map5').show();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

I'm using jQuery mobile, but also tested this separately from that. Sorry for being a help vampire - but I'm stumped and could really do with some help!

Comment: Try `document.getElementById`. And you define `radius` but use `$radius`. `$radius` is not defined.

Comment: var radius = getElementById('#radius'); if you use it like this remove the hash tag var radius = getElementById('radius'); but if you use jQuery why not var radius = $('#radius'); ?

Comment: Three answers, all correct, all different, and all incomplete -- because there are (at least) three different errors in that code.

Comment: Next time use the console of your browser to see what is going on. You likely have a few errors popping up there.

Comment: Side note: If you're using `else if`, there's no reason for the `($radius > xx &&` part of your following conditions...

Comment: Moreover, you may check your code http://stackoverflow.com/a/4071475/2375207 using http://www.jslint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various answers here have all focussed on different aspects of what's wrong *(lurkers: please upvote the helpful ones)*, so I'll sum them up in a community answer:

1. It's `else if` (note the space), not `elseif`.
2. You've used the variable name `radius`, but then when referencing it you use `$radius`. Either is fine, pick one and be consistent. I'll use `radius`.
3. Instead of `getElementById("#radius")`, use `$("#radius")`. (There were two different problems with the first version: 1. `getElementById` is a property of `document`, not a global. 2. You don't use a selector with it, just the ID.)
4. You're using `radius` as though it were a number, but it's an object (the DOM element if you use `getElementById`, a jQuery object if you use `$()`). So you probably want `.val()` there, too. And although JavaScript will convert the string to a number for you when you do things like `radius < 40`, it's usually best to parse it explicitly. So:

   ```
   var radius = parseInt($("#radius").val(), 10); // 10 = base 10
   ```
5. You haven't closed the call to `submit`, you need a `);` after the last `}` in your code.

Separately, if you're using `else if`, you don't need the initial `radius >= XX &&` part of the subsequent conditions.

Answer (score 2):

**Syntax error 1**,

```
 elseif($radius>40 && $radius<=80) {
//--^
```

Add a space over here in all of your `else if` block.

---

**Syntax error 2**,

use,

```
var radius =$('#radius').val();
```

instead of

```
var radius = getElementById('#radius');
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is with this line `var radius = getElementById('#radius');`

It should be

```
 $('#spot-search').submit(function (e) {
    var radius = parseInt($('#radius').val());

    if (radius <= 40) {
        $('#spot-search').hide();
        $('#map1').show();
    } else if (radius > 40 && radius <= 80) {
        $('#spot-search').hide();
        $('#map2').show();
    } else if (radius > 80 && radius <= 120) {
        $('#spot-search').hide();
        $('#map3').show();
    } else if (radius > 120 && radius <= 160) {
        $('#spot-search').hide();
        $('#map4').show();
    } else if (radius > 160 && radius <= 200) {
        $('#spot-search').hide();
        $('#map5').show();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

You need to use `parseInt` because the return type of `.val()` is string

Answer (score 1):

Add space between else if

```
$('#spot-search').submit(function (e) {
    var radius = $('#radius').val();

    if ($radius <= 40) {
        $('#spot-search').hide();
        $('#map1').show();
    } else if ($radius > 40 && $radius <= 80) {
        $('#spot-search').hide();
        $('#map2').show();
    } else if ($radius > 80 && $radius <= 120) {
        $('#spot-search').hide();
        $('#map3').show();
    } else if ($radius > 120 && $radius <= 160) {
        $('#spot-search').hide();
        $('#map4').show();
    } else if ($radius > 160 && $radius <= 200) {
        $('#spot-search').hide();
        $('#map5').show();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable name is `radius`, but you are referencing `$radius`.

Try:

```
var $radius = $('#radius');
```

Also, it is `else if` - not `elseif`

Answer (score 1):

You havent closed submit() function and elseif wants a better syntact

```
    $('#spot-search').submit(function (e) {
    var radius = $('#radius').val();

    if (radius <= 40) {
        $('#spot-search').hide();
        $('#map1').show();
    } else if ((radius > 40) && (radius <= 80)) {
        $('#spot-search').hide();
        $('#map2').show();
    } else if ((radius > 80) && (radius <= 120)) {
        $('#spot-search').hide();
        $('#map3').show();
    } else if ((radius > 120) && (radius <= 160)) {
        $('#spot-search').hide();
        $('#map4').show();
    } else if ((radius > 160) && (radius <= 200)) {
        $('#spot-search').hide();
        $('#map5').show();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```